# run my Asp.Net Web application on another machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How can I run my application on another machine, my team member wants to view the webpage in his computer. He doesn’t want to install visual studio but just wants to see the webpage in the browser.

I am using a Mac book

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Publish it to a web server, or have him install IIS on his machine and set it up.. wait.  That would be publishing to a web server.

In short, an ASP.NET website needs a web server to run.  Usually it's IIS, but if you have Visual Studio, it uses the built-in Cassini web server.  Either way, you need to have it in a web server of some kind.  You can't just run it as a stand-alone program.

I haven't' done this, but I think you COULD have it running in your computer in Visual Studio and still have him see it.  If you run it, you'll see that the address is in the format:

http://localhost/:[some port number]/YourWebAppName

If you have it running in Visual Studio on YOUR machine, your team member MAY be able to access it by changing "localhost" to your PC name.  It's worth a shot.

Otherwise, here are a bunch of links to how to publish your site, in case you're not sure.

http://www.google.com/search?q=publishing+asp.net+web+sites&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new virtual directory in IIS
2. Set the directory root to your project root folder.
3. allow anonymous access.

Your team member can then access it at http://yourmachinename/virtualdirectoryname

Comment: If you want to access your PC server over internet then you can use Opera Link (http://www.opera.com)

Comment: also check that your firewall is not blocking your IIS port

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good job for IIS express http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

For the majority of things, it's functionally equivilent to using regular IIS 7.5, with the exception that it's easier to start new websites with this.  You simply use the command line to start IIS Express, point it to your physical path, set the CLR version, and the port, done!

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/

There's some instructions for how to do that.