# Run aspx page locally in another computer without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that works fine in my computer locally. What I need is to run this application in another computer but it doesnt have Visual Studio.

I installed IIS 7.0 and tried to create a virtual directory but no luck. Am using the right port? Used port 80 and tried port 4444 and no luck. Any ideas?

What files do I have to drag into the inetpub/wwwroot? All my project files?

Comment: @dumass: you are wrong. Aspx file can be served without Visual Studio.  The OP just have to ensure to deploy the projet "builded"

Comment: @dumass All my web pages are aspx

Comment: @SteveB how would I do that? I am new at this

Comment: Right click your project and select "publish". Let the wizard guide you

Comment: possble dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270316/run-my-asp-net-web-application-on-another-machine

Comment: Or do a simple file copy on the target computer, and create an "application" in IIS (a simple virtual directory may be not enough). That said, please describe precisely what is the behavior, and what is the error message. There's maybe something wrong with your app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Visual Studio for a web application (aspx). You need to copy the files from the Bin folder and setup a Virtual directory (you do need IIS and might need to enable some features in IIS to support ASPX) .

The easiest way to do this is from Visual Studio right click your project and click **Publish**. This will let you select what kind of publish option you want (File System will publish to a local dir and you can just copy to the new computer and hook to the virtual directory you created, Web Deploy let's you remotely publish from your local dev box, etc.)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a walkthrough

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: I think this is a problem with IIS configuration with ASP.NET. Are you able to open other websites? 
If I remember correctly you might need to run "aspnet_regiis -i" if IIS was installed before ASP.NET in that machine. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.90).aspx/css

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're accessing the ASPX files through an IIS web server with the correct target framework you used then it can easily work without Visual Studio.

For instance, my production servers don't have Visual Studio on them. They just need IIS and the proper .NET framework installed.

As a commenter mentioned above, if you right click on your project and select PUBLISH you'll be in good hands.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Open sites
3. Right click on default website and choose "Add Application"
4. Alias "Application Name 'can be any' " and Physical Path is the application path

Comment: I used this method, but my links in website doesn't work! (error 404)